# Why can't I just remove a wrongly placed tag when editing a post

Tags: discussion, edits

Tried to remove a wrongly placed tag on another users post, but I was not allowed since I did not change at least 6 characters from the post itself.

This is weird, the post itself was nice, it just had nothing at all to do with the tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, that is status by design.

You need to wait until you get 2K to make those tiny (but meaningful) changes, *all by yourself*.

Comment: ok, makes sense, then this is more or less a bug report, showing a tag editor to the user if he has no rights to do so

Comment: @MichaelSander Nopes, not at all a bug. If you've edited more than 6 characters in the body, you've the rights to change the tag also. :)

Comment: Thats crazy logic to implement :D

Comment: @MichaelSander Why? How? How do you propose to _guess_ what changes a user is going to make to a post before he/she actually makes the change? Existing logic seems acceptable to me.

Comment: I got nothing against that logic, just wondering how many detailed exceptional rules there are on this page, like you can edit with 2k rep, or with xx rep if you are changing 6 characters as well. It wasn't obvious for me why I couldn't change that, This is maybe the missing part on the page.

Comment: I'm confused? I've edited quite some tags prior to reaching 2k, there was no blockage if you don't edit anything in the body. Has that changed?

Comment: Like @Gimby, I've also edited tags and I'm well below 2k.

Comment: Nonsense, the tag's name must be over 6 characters or it doesn't count! (I made that up).

Comment: So I'm not allowed to edit tags like 'C#' that have less than 6 characters? Thats does make sense :)