# Why can't I remove a tag?

Tags: discussion, support, bug, status-bydesign

This is a bug and should be fixed.

**[Here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/302505/why-cant-i-just-remove-a-wrongly-placed-tag-when-editing-a-post)** was asked before, and said you need had 2k rep, to bypass the 6 chars rule. But I have 15k so that doesn't work.

The question is obviously [postgresql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/postgresql). If I try to remove the wrong [mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mysql) tag, I have the message saying I made too few changes.

[image: enter code here]

So I have to delete [postgresql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/postgresql) and [mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mysql) tags and then add [postgresql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/postgresql) again

[image]

Comment: You'll get some great explanation that you need to make more edits - even when you cannot find any to make.  Surely you can add to the question, they'll say...

Comment: Seems odd - does it do the same if you just use the edit tag tool feature (by hovering next to the tags instead of going into the post to edit?)

Comment: @JonH I know if I change 6+ chars error disappear. But we shouldnt have to do extra changes if we want to add `C#, C++` tags

Comment: @JonClements I cant test it. After the first change looks like edit keep a count of my chars. I try use edit to add / removing `MySQL` again and no more errors.

Answer (score 43):

Turns out that there was [a pending suggested edit by another user](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/12005700) consisting of exactly the same as you were trying to do (removing the same tag). Thus the system detected your edit as "no changes relative to a pending change" and rejected it.

So, that's by design. But we're going to improve that error message.

**Edit:**

It's worth noting that this condition will happen only when two users are making *the same edit to the same post at the same time*; otherwise (pending edits are there when you navigate to the post), clicking the "edit" button will show you the pending edits list for review.

That said, as promised I have improved the error message. Now when you try to save an edit and another <2K rep user had suggested the same change, this is what you will see:

[image]

Comment: That make sense. Maybe a message saying there is already a pending edit.

Comment: could this thread be considered a bug report about the error message, then? so it can be followed up when that'll be fixed.

Comment: Plase fix the spelling, also consider fixing the comma splice.

Comment: @JeffreyBosboom Good catch, typo fixed. Thanks!

Comment: The only concern I have is that a high-rep user would be able to make the change without needing further review, but the low-rep user's change needs multiple approvals, which is wasted effort.  I know there's a credit to the low-rep user; maybe when a high-rep user makes the same change, the low-rep user's change should be approved automatically, like it is when you 'improve edit', even though there's nothing actually changing.  Whose name should show?  Probably the low-rep user's — they don't get their name shown very often yet.  But the low-rep user's edit should be cleared from the system.

Comment: Hopefully as well as fixing the typo you fixed the comma splice, as Jeffrey requested. I don't know when it became so fashionable to separate sentences with commas, but I wish you'd all stop it!

Comment: I just love the predictive edit summary :)